# how to install global angular-cli inside docker container?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, angular-cli

I created an image from my angular2 app created by angular-cli using below dockerfile.

```
FROM node:latest

MAINTAINER BHUSHAN GADEKAR

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=4200

COPY    .  /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www


RUN     npm install

EXPOSE  $PORT

ENTRYPOINT ["npm","start"]
```

After successful creation of image , I tried to run  this image using below command

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:4200 -w "/var/www" bhushan001/angular2-cli npm start
```

Now I can see my container getting started.but it runs into error that:

> ng serve "npm" "start" sh: 1: ng: not found

So I know that angular-cli is not present inside my container but I had installed it locally using `npm install` in dockerfile.

any inputs?

thanks in advance.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: install angular-cli globally in your container ie `npm install -g angular-cli` ?

Answer (score 1):

use `bash -c -l 'npm start'` - this ensure your ENV is populated, which you need.